# Why is the CSS attribute ‘stroke’ named so?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is the CSS attribute ‘stroke’ named so?

I find no dictionary meaning of stroke as border/outline, isn’t that what the attribute does, defining the properties of border/outline?

Shouldn’t the attribute have been named border/outline instead?

Comment: I voted to leave open since the main question is about history, not opinion. The last sentence ("should…") is about opinion but that doesn't seem to be the main point.

Answer (score 1):

stroke is just a line which you draw.It is a mark made by a pen or pencil across a paper or canvas. Like in layman language we say to create a pencil stroke, it's meaning is the same as drawing a border or an outline in whatever context you want to interpret. :)

Answer (score 0):

SVG offers a wide range of stroke properties.

stroke
stroke-width
stroke-linecap
stroke-dasharray

All the stroke properties can be applied to any kind of lines, text and outlines of elements like a circle.

Comment: And just a side note: You can only use stroke on SVG's :)

Comment: @Lirianna And when drawing on a canvas with JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

It's historical. Stroke is used for the same thing in several older languages, [such as postscript](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall01/cps100/assign/recursivegraph/postscript-help.htm). I'm not sure, but I think the first time I saw the word was for some plotter in the 1980s.

**EDIT:** This doesn't really answer why, just punts to an older why. Languages like Postscript treat a rectangle not as a surface with a bounday, but rather as a polygon with 90-degree angles, and a polygon is just a polyline whose end point is its start point. A polyline is composed of strokes or segments, and all the specialisations inherit the name.